# Como resolver erro mysql_query?

Tags: mysql

Instalei um sistema de login e cadastro em uma hospedagem, ajustei o banco de dados e conectei com o sistema, inclusive criei um usuário para testar o login. No entanto quando vou logar ele apresenta esses erros:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /srv/disk5/2615118/www/ge2018.atspace.eu/classes/Login.class.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /srv/disk5/2615118/www/ge2018.atspace.eu/classes/Login.class.php on line 5
```

O código referente ao erro segue abaixo:

```js
<?php
 class Login{
  public function logar($email, $senha){
   $buscar=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha' LIMIT 1");
   if(mysql_num_rows($buscar) == 1){
    $dados=mysql_fetch_array($buscar);
    if($dados["status"] == 1){
     $_SESSION["email"]=$dados["email"];
     $_SESSION["senha"]=$dados["senha"];
     $_SESSION["nivel"]=$dados["nivel"];
     setcookie("logado",1);
     $log=1;
    }else{
     $flash="Aguarde a nossa aprovação!";
    }
   }
    if(isset($log)){
     $flash="Você foi logado com sucesso";
    }else{
     if(empty($flash)){
     $flash="Ops! Digite seu e-mail e sua senha corretamente!";
     }
    }
    echo $flash;
  }
 
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A função mysqli_query requer 2 parâmetros:

1. Conexão
2. Query a ser executada.

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","senha","bancodedados");
// verifica conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Falha ao conectar com MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// roda a query
mysqli_query($con,"WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha' LIMIT 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note que antes da query, passamos também a conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: Fiz as mudanças e da o mesmo erro!